# If/Else statement not functioning properly (Else statement won't function in particular)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a script that manages the visibility of content based on whether a certain option is selected. The issue I am running into is that my if/else statement is not functioning properly.

It shows the div `.provider-info` when the last `.radial-container` radio button is checked (i.e. "I would like to keep my number").

It's supposed to `slideUp` when the class `.select` is removed from the parent container, but it doesn't.

I experimented a bit and was able to gain the functionality I was looking for with a different piece of code:

```
 $(function() {
  $('.radial-container').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('select').siblings().removeClass('select');
    if($('.radial-container').last().hasClass('select')) {
      $(this).children('.provider-info').slideDown(300);
    } else {
      $('.provider-info').slideUp(300);
    }
  })
})
```

But the issue with the above segment is that it only works with Unlimited Line 2. Unlimited Line 1 essentially loses functionality.

How can I fix this code in order to get the if/else statement to function properly? I only want the div `.provider-info` to be visible when the 2nd radio button is selected.

Thanks,

-M

```js
$(function() {
  $('.radial-container').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('select').siblings().removeClass('select');
    if($('.radial-container').hasClass('select')) {
      $(this).children('.provider-info').slideDown(300);
    } else {
      $('.provider-info').slideUp(300);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.phn-option-container {
 display:block;
}

.phn-unl {
 position:relative;
 margin:40px 0;
}

.phn-unl:after {
 content:'';
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 background:#e8e8e8;
 height:1px;
 top:30px;
 clear:both;
}

.radial-container {
 display:block;
 cursor: pointer;
 clear:both;
}

.phn-radio-container {
 margin:10px;
 clear:both;
}

.phn-unl > h4 {
 position:relative;
 left:10px;
 font-weight:600;
 color:#22ddc0;
}

.radial-container p {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 left:25px;
 top:17px;
 color:#787878;
}

.radial-container.select .phn-radial .phn-center-dot {
 display:block;
}

.phn-radial {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 height:35px;
 width:35px;
 padding:2px;
 margin:10px 0;
 border:5px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-radius:50%;
 left:10px;
 clear:both;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.phn-center-dot {
 display:none;
 position:relative;
 height:21px;
 width:21px;
 background-color:#E16E5B;
 border-radius:50%;
}

.provider-info label {
 color:#787878;
 margin:25px 0 0 60px;
}

.provider-info label span {
 position:relative;
 color:#E16E5B;
 top:-3px;
}

.provider-info input {
 background-color:transparent;
 border-width:0 0 2px;
 border-color:#787878;
 border-radius:0;
 margin-left:10px;
 width:270px;
 font-size:16px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}

.provider-info input:focus {
 border-color:#22ddc0;
 outline:0;
}

.provider-info {
 display:none;
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phn-option-container">
          <div class="phn-unl" data-unl-line="1">
            <h4>Unlimited Line 1</h4>
            <div class="radial-container select">
              <div class="phn-radial">
                <div class="phn-center-dot"></div>
              </div>
              <p>I would like a <strong>new</strong> number</p>
            </div>
            <div class="radial-container">
              <div class="phn-radial">
                <div class="phn-center-dot"></div>
              </div>
              <p>I would like to <strong>keep</strong> my number</p>
              <div class="provider-info">
                <div>
                  <label>Current Number: <span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. (555) 555-5555"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label>Current Provider: <span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Verizon"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="phn-unl" data-unl-line="2">
            <h4>Unlimited Line 2</h4>
            <div class="radial-container select">
              <div class="phn-radial">
                <div class="phn-center-dot"></div>
              </div>
              <p>I would like a <strong>new</strong> number</p>
            </div>
            <div class="radial-container">
              <div class="phn-radial">
                <div class="phn-center-dot"></div>
              </div>
              <p>I would like to <strong>keep</strong> my number</p>
              <div class="provider-info">
                <div>
                  <label>Current Number: <span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. (555) 555-5555"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label>Current Provider: <span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Verizon"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
$('.radial-container').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('select')
           .siblings('.radial-container')
           .removeClass('select')
           .find('.provider-info')
           .slideUp(300);
    $('.provider-info', this).slideDown(300);
});
```

Fixed Demo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.radial-container').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('select')
               .siblings('.radial-container')
               .removeClass('select')
               .find('.provider-info')
               .slideUp(300);
        $('.provider-info', this).slideDown(300);
    });
});
```

```css
.phn-option-container {
 display:block;
}

.phn-unl {
 position:relative;
 margin:40px 0;
}

.phn-unl:after {
 content:'';
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 background:#e8e8e8;
 height:1px;
 top:30px;
 clear:both;
}

.radial-container {
 display:block;
 cursor: pointer;
 clear:both;
}

.phn-radio-container {
 margin:10px;
 clear:both;
}

.phn-unl > h4 {
 position:relative;
 left:10px;
 font-weight:600;
 color:#22ddc0;
}

.radial-container p {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 left:25px;
 top:17px;
 color:#787878;
}

.radial-container.select .phn-radial .phn-center-dot {
 display:block;
}

.phn-radial {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 height:35px;
 width:35px;
 padding:2px;
 margin:10px 0;
 border:5px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-radius:50%;
 left:10px;
 clear:both;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.phn-center-dot {
 display:none;
 position:relative;
 height:21px;
 width:21px;
 background-color:#E16E5B;
 border-radius:50%;
}

.provider-info label {
 color:#787878;
 margin:25px 0 0 60px;
}

.provider-info label span {
 position:relative;
 color:#E16E5B;
 top:-3px;
}

.provider-info input {
 background-color:transparent;
 border-width:0 0 2px;
 border-color:#787878;
 border-radius:0;
 margin-left:10px;
 width:270px;
 font-size:16px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}

.provider-info input:focus {
 border-color:#22ddc0;
 outline:0;
}

.provider-info {
 display:none;
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phn-option-container">
          <div class="phn-unl" data-unl-line="1">
            <h4>Unlimited Line 1</h4>
            <div class="radial-container select">
              <div class="phn-radial">
                <div class="phn-center-dot"></div>
              </div>
              <p>I would like a <strong>new</strong> number</p>
            </div>
            <div class="radial-container">
              <div class="phn-radial">
                <div class="phn-center-dot"></div>
              </div>
              <p>I would like to <strong>keep</strong> my number</p>
              <div class="provider-info">
                <div>
                  <label>Current Number: <span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. (555) 555-5555"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label>Current Provider: <span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Verizon"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="phn-unl" data-unl-line="2">
            <h4>Unlimited Line 2</h4>
            <div class="radial-container select">
              <div class="phn-radial">
                <div class="phn-center-dot"></div>
              </div>
              <p>I would like a <strong>new</strong> number</p>
            </div>
            <div class="radial-container">
              <div class="phn-radial">
                <div class="phn-center-dot"></div>
              </div>
              <p>I would like to <strong>keep</strong> my number</p>
              <div class="provider-info">
                <div>
                  <label>Current Number: <span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. (555) 555-5555"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label>Current Provider: <span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. Verizon"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Nice, simple solution. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

do you want to use
$(this).children in the else block as well?

```
 $(this).children('.provider-info').slideDown(300);
} else {
  $(this).children('.provider-info').slideUp(300);
```